# Windows Explorer - Treating cameras/Android file systems like disks and sort by date

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, android, sorting, mtp

My Android current, and previous, Samsung phones identify as a camera (technically a media device) to Windows.  They do this because they have internal flash and to mount the file system to another device they have to share it.  Sounds good in theory, but the performance kind of sucks, and you get a weird phenomenon like Windows doesn't treat the files and folders the same as another disk or drive.  Which is annoying when you just want drive access.

The sort order for the folders is by default Name, Ascending.  Usually, I want to change that to Date, Ascending so that I get the most recent stuff up top so I can find what I am looking for.

However, if, in Windows Explorer, I right click in some white space, and attempt to change the sort order, I am greeted with media-specific sort options.  None of which are useful, because I just want "Date".  See below:

[image: Windows Explorer sort by options]

Now, I understand that I can click the More... button to go modify the menu to show "Created", which is effectively "Date", but, unfortunately, those changes do not stick around the next time I plug in the Android device.

**Questions**

1. What changes can I make to get rid of the annoying media-centric sort options?
2. Are there software/packages I can download/install to change this behavior? (In either Windows or Android)
3. Is there some other approach I can take to make the Android device get treated like just another drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a name on the style of device you see;
It is either using the most recent "Media Transfer Protocol" or the previous "Picture Transfer Protocol" (MTP/PTP devices). There is some "affiliation" with DRM here.

Note that some devices are switchable between this mode and e.g. "Mass storage device" (e.g. a Nikon D300).

I have yet to find any useful replacement or tweak for the MTP-mode. 
I went back to using a card reader (probably not an option for an Android device) and Dropbox (for transfer of data from internal non-removable memory, Android).

More info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: The card reader idea only works if you are using the SD card.  In this case, the information is on the internal flash, so I can't really pull that out.

Comment: Then, the only option you have is to use the MTP mode stuff that exists.